# Is there a Shortcut for "Mark all messages as read" in Outlook?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to find a shortcut for marking all messages (eMails) in a folder as read by using a keyboard shortcut, but had no luck in finding one so far.

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2010 and when I open the context menu (right click on the folder), it shows the "e" underlined in "Mark All as Read", which is in my opinion a sign for a shortcut.

Does anybody know the shortcut?

Comment: I know you've gotten a satisfactory answer, but just wanted to mention that the underlined _e_ that you see is a shortcut only when the contextual menu is visible... i.e. it still requires the click.

Comment: Which context menu contains the item 'Mark *all* as read'? I can see a 'Mark as read' item when I highlight one or many messages and bring up the context menu. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Some keyboards have a [menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) that simulates a context-click. It's usually between right ALT and right CTRL. It looks like a cursor hovering over a menu.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could put the "Mark All as Read" command into the Quick Access Toolbar like so:
[image: Quick Access Toolbar customization dialog]

After that you can access the function via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. The number depends on the position where you place the command. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> by itself to make Outlook display overlays for all hotkeys.

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I really want to avoid to click.

Comment: @Bertolt You only have to set it up once, after that the hotkey is permanently available.

Comment: Oops, I did not get that elements in the quick access toolbar get automatically assigned to a keyboard shortcut. NIce solution.

Comment: The thing that it works for whole folder makes it easier to deal with dozens of emails that happen to come during the day.1

Comment: All Commands from the Choose command from drop down list if you can't see:  Mark All as Read

Answer (score 15):

**Keyboard shortcut**

Click any message in the message list, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Comment: Quite close. But is there a way of doing exactly that without clicking on a message?

Comment: This is slow in a large inbox, but works. I have 25,545 items in my inbox and 4,778 unread items. Outlook became unresponsive for a minute when I pressed CTRL+A to select all. When I pressed CTRL+Q to mark all as read, a dialog appeared for a minute to show a progress bar. After another minute, I have no unread emails. Thanks!

Comment: Also works in Courrier for Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the folder the emails are in then use:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> - This brings up the context menu on the folder in Mac Outlook

<kbd>E</kbd> - This selects 'Mark all as Read' in the context menu

Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you saying that three keys should be pressed together?

Comment: The use of Option + Command + T is better for this case but THANK YOU A TON for letting me know about the Shift + F10 functionality!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> works in Mac in Version 16.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. Do I have to press three keys together? I have only one E key. I tried holding ALT and pressing E twice while focused on the message pane but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just select/highlight them all (click first message, scroll to last message hold SHIFT and click again) and then press "Read".

Comment: This sounds equivalent to the (Ctrl+A), (Ctrl+Q) answer, but more work.

Comment: When you have an inbox with 25,000 messages it's hard to scroll to the last message. It does work, though.

Answer (score 0):

To mark all messages as read within a folder , try the following seq Alt+O+MA
Works on Office 365 ProPlus. version 1906.

Alt+F3 used to work on older version but not on newer outlook anymore.