# How can I mark all messages as read?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

How can I mark all messages as read in Outlook?

(Not the same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/385173/is-there-a-shortcut-for-mark-all-messages-as-read-in-outlook) which is Windows-specific)

Comment: Asked because I noticed there was no OSX version of this question, and I found the Windows version because I needed to know the answer and it was non-obvious (to me, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Three different ways of doing this:

- Under the "Message" menu at the top of the screen, click "Mark All As Read".
- Use the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Select all messages via <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and mark them all as read using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.